# Difference to previous year, loop through all years, in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following SQL query as a custom connector to BigQuery from Google Sheets. It compares the performances of people between two years, by finding the difference between a person's performance one year and the performance of the same person the previous year. I then output MeanDiff, Standard Deviation and Count, of all persons who have performances in both years.

```html
WITH ct AS
(
  SELECT  
  PersonID,
  Performance,
  Year,
  LAG(Performance)
    OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Year ) AS previous_year,
  TIME_DIFF(Performance, '0:0:0', second) / LAG(TIME_DIFF(Performance, '0:0:0', second))
   OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Year ) AS diff
FROM `results_2000_2023` 
WHERE Year=2022 OR Year=2023
)
SELECT
    MAX(Year)-1 AS Year1, MAX(Year) AS Year2, AVG(diff) AS MeanDiff, STDDEV(diff) AS SD, COUNT(diff) AS Count
FROM
    ct
WHERE
    diff <> 0
```

Now I can compare two years, by adding those years as WHERE Year=2022 OR WHERE Year=2023. But what if I want a table with all comparisons to the previous year?

Like this:

```
| Year1 | Year2 | MeanDiff |  SD  | Count |
|-------|-------|----------|------|-------|
| 2000  | 2001  |  0.9643  | 0.08 |  5430 |
| 2001  | 2002  |  1.0232  | 0.05 |  4430 |
| 2002  | 2003  |  0.9714  | 0.03 |  7430 |
| 2003  | 2004  |  0.9435  | 0.10 |  3430 |
```

How can I make such a loop through all years from say 2000 up to 2023? I tried wrapping the above SQL query in a WHILE loop, but apparently that's now how it's supposed to be done.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Daniel Westergren, Can you try using `Between` syntax like

`WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2` as mentioned in this [documentation](https://blog.coupler.io/bigquery-between/) ?